# How not remove "index.html"?

Tags: angular, angular6, router

I have a problem with my Angular 6 app.

My app url : my-server/my-app/index.html.

When the app is loaded, the url is automaticaly rewrited without the "index.html".
It's a big problem because deep links are unusable.

Exemple : my-server/my-app/deep-route-1/6

The app work well, but if an user want to copy/paste this deep link, the server http respond 404 (and it's normal i think).

How to solve this problem?

Here my routes declaration:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  //{ path: '', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'simulation/:id', component: SimulateurComponent, resolve: { vm: SimulationResolver } },
  { path: 'parametres/:nedt', component: ParamsComponent, resolve: { params: ParamsResolver } }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
```

EDIT

After searchs, it seems it's a new particularity of Angluar.io.
Angular 6 use "html 5 urls" that's why he automaticaly remove the "index.html" in the url.

To counter that, 2 solutions :
- A complicated (rewrite url) - no time to test it
- A simple : use the angular.js technique :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true }) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

The "usehash" is magic ;)

Comment: Configure your server to respond with the index.html document if an unknown URL is requested.

Comment: What server technology are you using? Apache? Nginx? or? You need rewrite rules to forward all requests to the index.html, then your deep links will work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i precise my server is correctly configured.
I have others apps in angular 1 and all url are index.html#/ work well
It's angular 6 who remove the index.html and i want to block that.
(i use IIS on window server)

Comment: Are you telling me than a server can try all folders by cascading until he found a valid folder/index.html file ?

Comment: No, you'll just tell your server to redirect every failing request to /index.html

Comment: This Angular/IIS article might help you: https://blog.angularindepth.com/deploy-an-angular-application-to-iis-60a0897742e7

Comment: Thanks for the article it's really interesting !

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I just had the same exact problem.

I solved it by changing the build command that i use during deployment:

BEFORE (NOT working, removes index.html :( )

```
ng build --base-href /www/app/
```

After (WORKS, doesn't remove index.html :) )

```
ng build --base-href /www/app/index.html
```